# Counting number of repeated numbers in loop and print

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, numbers, repeat

```
for (int l = 1; j < 5; l++) {
    int l = (int)(Math.random()*5) +1;      
    System.out.print(l + ",");
}
```

I generate a random number between 1-5 five times but instead of printing it out like this:

```
1, 3, 3, 5, 5
```

I would only like to print out something like this

```
1 has been printed once
3 has been printed twice
5 has been printed twice
```

In summary, I would like to only count the number of repeated and non repeated integers in the loop and then print it.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Why not try to code it and see how it goes?

Comment: Maybe store the count in a HashMap?

Comment: `(int l = 1; j < 5; l++)` ?

Comment: i <5 *. I cant seem to have any ideas about how to code it..

Comment: Well, step away from the computer, pull out a pencil and some paper, an see how *you*, as a human, would code it. What steps do you take? Can you break those down? How might you change those steps into instructions you give to someone else? And how might you turn those instructions into code? You shouldn't be using SO as a place to get your thinking done for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare

```
int[] anArray = new int[6];
```

then in the loop:

```
int l = (int)(Math.random()*5) +1;
anArray[l]++;
System.out.print(l + "appeared" + anArray[l] + "times.");
```

Now you can print the frequency.

Comment: You are welcome. This method can be used in many situations. Please accept the answer if it fits your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could approach this.

The one I would suggest is to use the values you generate as index values for an array, and have each value in the array indicate how many times that number shows up. For example, if you have an array called "numCount"...

```
numCount[0] = // number of times 0 was generated
numCount[1] = // number of times 1 was generated
numCount[2] = // number of times 2 was generated
// And so on...
```

And so on. Your loop would replace the println statement with something similar to this :

```
numCount[l]++; // Increments the counter for whatever value l is by one
```

Side note : Use meaningful names for your variables! I know this may be a small code snippet, but "l" is extremely vague.

In retrospect this strikes me as very likely a homework question... Ah well.